# What are naming rules of templates in django class based views

Tags: django, django-templates, django-class-based-views

When using class-based views, many of them have default rule to automatically search a template so we don't need to specify it every time we use a class-based view.

But I can't find any article writes about how default naming is done.

What are the rules to define default template name?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can give template name as `model_viewtype.html`

Example: if model name is **Abcd**

- for ListView:  `abcd_list.html`
- for CreateView: `abcd_form.html`
- for DetailView: `abcd_detail.html`

And if you still face issues, the **debugger** will suggest you.

Answer (score 2):

Well if you don't create template, debugger is telling you which template you need to create. So if you want try it one by one. Otherwise use template_name = 'example.html'